# Select max Id from output of executing a prepare statement result

Tags: mysql

I have the following prepare statement in which I have kept the limit clause variable -

```
PREPARE fooStmt FROM "SELECT id FROM Table_1 ORDER BY id LIMIT ?";
```

I define a variable @record -

```
SET @record = 4;
```

Now I use the above variable to execute the prepared statement -

```
EXECUTE fooStmt USING @record;
```

I get the below result -

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
|  4 |
+----+
```

Now my problem is that I want the max id from the above result. 
I tried the below query for obtaining the desired result, but it gives me SQL syntax error :

```
select max(id) from (EXECUTE fooStmt USING @record);
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'USING @record)' at line 1
```

Can you please help me to identify the problem and how can I get my desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this please:

```
PREPARE fooStmt
FROM "SELECT max(id) AS id FROM ( SELECT id FROM frameThreshold ORDER BY id LIMIT ? ) AS id";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need you should (re)prepare the sql

```
 "select max(id) from 
         (SELECT id FROM Table_1 ORDER BY id LIMIT ?) as t";
```

then

```
 PREPARE your_maxFooStmt FROM  "select max(id) from 
         (SELECT id FROM Table_1 ORDER BY id LIMIT ?) as t";
```